# ¿Cómo capturar una ruta de red UNC desde un .bat?

Tags: cmd, vbscript

Me gustaría saber si existe una forma de capturar la ruta desde la cual se ejecuta un archivo .bat siendo esta una carpeta de red. Si intento llamar a la variable de entorno %cd% desde un script lanzado en una carpeta de red, me dice lo siguiente:

```
'\\xx.nn.ii.oo\scripts'
CMD.EXE se inició con esta ruta como el directorio actual. No se permiten
rutas UNC. Regresando de manera predeterminada al directorio Windows.
current directory: C:\Windows
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

He estado buscando por Internet si existía otra variable que almacenara dicha ruta, pero de momento no he tenido suerte, de no existir, ¿Hay alguna solución para capturar dicha ruta?

-- EDITADO --

En el script se lanzan varios archivos .vbs (visual basic script) haciendo uso de cscript de Windows Script Hosts, en caso de que no se pueda capturar desde cmd de ninguna forma ¿se podría capturar desde el archivo .vbs?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de resolverlo directamente desde el bat es usar : **`%~dp0`** que en el contexto de un programa batch expandirá a la ruta completa del mismo, por ejemplo:

```
echo La ruta actual desde dónde se ejecuta el path es:
echo %~dp0
```

`%~dp0` Se divide de la siguiente forma:

- `%0`: expande el nombre del archivo `BAT`
- `%~0`: `~` remueve las comillas dobles
- `%dp0`: `d` y `p` son modificadores de la expansión, `d` fuerza el agregado del la letra del drive si corresponde y `p` agrega el path completo

Para más información te recomiendo: [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente, me ha solucionado el problema que tenia.